# How to get HTML source of a page after javascript is loaded using Swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, nsurl

Trying to figure out how I can get the html source of a url after Javascript and everything has been loaded. My code below only seems to get the HTML before javascript or anything has been loaded.

```
let testUrl = NSURL(string: "myurl.com") 
do { let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36 
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: testUrl) request.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent") 
var response:NSURLResponse? = nil; 
var error:NSError? = nil; 
do { 
var data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response) 
print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web browser like Safari fetches html file from server just like what your code do. But Web browser will also parse the html file and find all the javascript link, css link, image link... and download them all.